# MySQL count function with a join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables.
User(id,name)
Finance(id,item_id,amount,user_id)

My use case is

users are the employees (sales guys) of the organization.

When they sell an item finance table get updated with a new record of that sold item's serial id.

I want to get the user names along with the total value of the sales they made.

User

```
id  |  name
1   |  Dinesh
2   |  Pathum
3   |  Naveed
```

Finance

```
id  | item_id | amount | user_id
1   | 1       | 2000   | 1
2   | 2       | 2000   | 1
3   | 3       | 1000   | 3
4   | 4       | 500    | 3
```

Expected output

```
Dinesh 4000
Pathum 0
Naveed 1500
```

How do I achieve this using MySQL?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: The solution is quite easy. Try something with (left) join and group by

Comment: @RobertKock SELECT Accounts.* FROM info_travel.Accounts inner join Finances on Accounts.id = Finances.user_id; upto this I did

Comment: You should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is like the following:

```
SELECT u.name as 'Agent Name', 
if(sum(f.amount) IS NULL, 0,sum(f.amount)) as Total,
f.createdAt
FROM users u LEFT JOIN finance f
ON u.id = f.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, f.createdAt
ORDER BY f.createdAt DESC
```

Here is a working [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pt8tTqRo95uks58E17PMj/0).

Comment: This won't give Pathum 0

Comment: I didn't try but I think it'll report 'null' for Pathum.

Comment: No. It will give 0. The sum function return a number.

Comment: I can make you an sql fiddle if you wait for 10 minutes.

Comment: Check out the comment within the other answer

Comment: @alim1990 the finance table has createdAt column and I want to filter it by date range. All I need to do is add the where clause right after the group by clause?

Comment: Add order by after group by

Comment: ORDER BY f.your_column DESC

Answer (score 1):

Join em, group em, sum em.

```
SELECT usr.name AS UserName, COALESCE(SUM(fin.amount),0) AS TotalAmount
FROM `User` usr
LEFT JOIN `Finance` fin ON fin.user_id = usr.id
GROUP BY usr.id, usr.name
ORDER BY usr.id;
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1126abc85196d860230af37b2beaef9e)*

Comment: This won't give Pathum 0

Comment: I didn't try but I think it'll report 'null' for Pathum.

Comment: That's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
SELECT Name,SUM(IFNULL(amount,0)) AS "Total" FROM (SELECT Name,amount FROM user LEFT JOIN finance ON user.id=finance.user_id) a GROUP BY Name;
```